# Test a connection failure during a route test using ScalaTest and Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, scalatest, akka-http

I have a route that takes an id, looks for that id in the database, and then updates the row if the id exists:

```
    pathPrefix("rules") {
          path(JavaUUID) { inputId =>
            put {
                onComplete(Database.findById(inputId)) {
                  case Success(Some(row)) => complete {
                      Database.update(row.copy(test = true))
                        .map { _ => StatusCodes.OK -> "success" }
                        .recover { case _ => StatusCodes.InternalServerError -> "updateFail"}
                    }
                  }
                  case Success(None) => complete(StatusCodes.NotFound -> "idNotFound")
                  case Failure(_) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError -> "findIdFail")
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

I am able to test for the `Database.findById()` failure by just closing the database connection from the start of a test like so:

```
"return 500 Internal Server Error when DB connection not working" in {
  val tempDatabase = Database.forConfig("aurora")
  tempDatabase.close()
  Put(disablePath) ~> EnforceRow()(as, tempDatabase))~> check {
    status shouldEqual StatusCodes.InternalServerError
    val response = responseAs[String]
    response shouldBe """{"message": "findIdFail."}"""
  }
}
```

However, I am trying to test for the case when the `Database.update` method fails and returns `500 Internal Server Error`. Is there a way to know within a test when the `findById` method has finished so that I can then close the db connection so that the `update` method fails?

Answer (score 0):

With method whenReady() from [ScalaTest](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures)

```
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures  
import org.scalatest.{FunSuite, Matchers}

class DatabaseFutures extends FunSuite with Matchers with ScalaFutures {

    test("your test") {
          whenReady(Database.findById(inputId)) {
           ....
          Database.close
        ....
    }    
}
```